# Как из строки выделить переменную?

Tags: php

есть строка (var_dump приведён ниже) из неё необхоимо выделить переменную sum.
Пробовал explode, но не получилось. Есть кто уже сталкивался с таким?

string(76) "{"sum": "20.00", "sum_btc": 0, "sum_exmo": "0.6068965517241379226121011925"}"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это json

```
$obj = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->sum;
```

Comment: Гений! От души спасибо вам большое за помощь джуну!